# How to make a select on different table in function of an argument?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In function of myVariable, this select is made from a different table.

```
select 
     *
from
    table(decode(myVariable,1,sys.odcinumberlist(1,2),sys.odcinumberlist(3)))
```

result

if myVAriable =1 then 1,2
else                  3

I would like to to make the same thing but instead of having sys.odcinumberlist, I would like to have the list of all integer inferior than 100.

I have tried a lot of way to do that. This for instance, but none has worked

```
select *
from
    table(decode(myvariable,1,table(select level from dual connect by level<100),sys.odcinumberlist(3)))
```

wanted result:

myvariable =1  then 1,2,3....99
else                 3

Comment: Where does `myvariable` comes from?

Comment: @GMB the select is used in a PL/SQL script that i haven't rewrite completely. You only have replace myVariable by a number if you want to test the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast this subquery as `odcinumberlist`:

```
select * from
    table(decode(myvariable, 1,
                   cast(multiset(
                        select level from dual connect by level<100) 
                        as sys.odcinumberlist),
                   sys.odcinumberlist(3)))
```